# ejs 2 custom delimiter

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

EJS2 can only do character to be use with angle brackets for open/close:

```
ejs.delimiter = '$';
ejs.render('<$= users.join(" | "); $>', {users: users});
```

I would like to use `{{ }}` instead of `<% %>`, previous version will allow this `esj.open = '{{'` and `esj.close = '}}'`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible without modifying the [module's source code](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/b777b06d08b6714b3856c92f133d823af3635263/lib/ejs.js#L53).

Answer (score 3):

EJS has been updated & changed maintainers, so the main site is found here: https://ejs.co/ 
and the Github is here: https://github.com/mde/ejs

Unlike previous versions of EJS, you can't use completely custom delimiters now - you can use 'partial' custom delimiters - the first set of brackets aren't optional, but the following character is. To set up a custom delimiter you can do the following:

```
// app.js
const ejs = require('ejs');
ejs.delimiter = '?';
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        myVariable: 'Hey!'
    });
});

// index.ejs
<div>
    <p>
    <?=myVariable ?>
    </p>
</div>

// index.html (rendered output)
<div>
    <p>
    Hey!
    </p>
</div>
```

You can add a complete options object and other things, but hopefully that gets you started if you want to change the default delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation states that custom delimiters are supported:

https://github.com/tj/ejs#custom-delimiters

Answer (score -2):

My solution to using custom delimiters is be doing a string replace on the template

```
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './template.html'), 'utf8').replace('{{', '<%').replace('}}', '%>')

const render = ejs.compile(template)
```

This allows me to declare my template like this:

```
{{ if (someVar) { }}
  {{= someVar }}
{{ } }}
```

Comment: This will also replace minified js/css code inside html file example : `@media (min-width:100px){body{background:#000;}}` in css and `if(a>b){if(b>c){//something;}}` anyway you got the idea. And it is extra effort if the html file is too large.

Comment: Basic find replace is bad practice as in most cases like @27px states, you'll end up with no shortage of false positives, not accounting for nesting, etc as opposed to an actual lexer which is going to take that into account. Evaluating an AST is completely different than evaluating one large block of text.